# What's the best way to round monetary amounts to the nearest nickel, quarter, $1, $5, etc. denominations?

Tags: c++, sql, algorithm, rounding, informix

Canada announced that they will no longer mint pennies and the U.S. Treasury is strongly contemplating following suit! That implies that monetary amounts will have to be rounded to the nearest nickel, thus requiring a lot of programming modifications!.. In the pawnshop business, we've been rounding loan amounts to the nearest $5 denominations, e.g. 50, 55, 60.. when the calculated loan falls between $50 and $100, to the nearest $10 denomination above $100, etc. Its common practice in order to minimize the use of smaller denomination bills. So what is a good algorithm for rounding to the nearest desired denomination?

In SQL, could I create a user-defined datatype to round to n-denomination, or is it better to leave the decimal(8,2) datatype alone and round with a function?

Comment: Is this homework? Pretty sure the US treasury hasn't announced anything like that yet.

Comment: Also, are you looking for a SQL solution, or a general solution?

Comment: it was on ABC news today and yes, i'm looking for an SQL and C++ solution

Comment: @FrankComputer I think you mean Canada is discontinuing the penny not America http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/headlines/2012/03/u-s-penny-to-be-kept-as-canada-bids-coin-farewell/

Comment: well i heard different, i heard U.S. will also do it!.. it makes sense, savings on raw materials, manufacturing, time consumption, etc.

Comment: even if the U.S. doesn't do it and Canada does, we would have to retool software since we do a lot of business with Canada, but i'm willing to bet the U.S. will follow suit if Canada does it!.. even a U.S. Nickel currently cost over 11 cents to manufacture!

Comment: so basically, you're all saying that no program mods will be necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to use in SQL:

```
new_val = ROUND(old_value * 20) / 20;
```

And when nickels go the way of cents, then:

```
new_val = ROUND(old_value * 10) / 10;
```

This works fine in SQL with DECIMAL or NUMERIC values; it also works well with SQL FLOAT and a little less reliably with SQL SMALLFLOAT (simply because SMALLFLOAT may only have about 6 decimal digits of accuracy).  The same basic technique can be used in C++ if the `old_value` is a `double` (more dubiously if it is a `float`, for the same reason that SQL SMALLFLOAT is problematic).  In C++ or C, you'd use the `<cmath>` or `<math.h>` header to obtain a declaration for the function `round()` or `roundf()`.  If you're using ESQL/C and `dec_t`, then you need `decround(&dec_value, 0);`.

In ESQL/C, you have provide the number of places to round to, and you'd have to code the multiply and divide, too.  Assuming you have a decimal value `dec_20` somewhere containing the value `20`, you'd write:

```
dec_t new_val;
decmul(&old_val, &dec_20, &new_val);
decround(&new_val, 0);
decdiv(&new_val, &dec_20, &new_val);
```

You might error check `decmul()` and `decdiv()`; there is no return value from `decround()` to do an error check on.  It is safe to use one of the inputs as the output in the last line.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have your numbers as something like: `44.32`, then all you need to do (this is pseudocode, the implementation in c++ should be trivial):

```
findmod = (num_to_be_changed*100)%5
if findmod <= 2
  new_num = num_to_be_changed - findmod
else 
  new_num = num_to_be_changed +  (5 - findmod)
end
new_num = new_num/100
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a technical answer per se to the question, but a point to be considered. You may find that your "programmatic modifications" are illusory.

When Australia phased out 1 and 2 cent coins in the 1990s, rounding of amounts was only performed on cash transactions, and this is still the case. Card payments are charged to the cent. Likewise, telephone and other utility bills are charged to the cent, but rounded to the nearest 5c when (and only when) paid in cash over the counter. And of course, share trading and currency exchange continue to be dealt with in fractions of cents or pennies.

So if you can assume that the number of cash transactions rounded down (those ending in 1, 2, 6 or 7c) is roughly the same as the number rounded up (3, 4, 8 or 9c), then the only effect is that the cash register may be out by a few cents at the end of the day. In fact, it is more likely to be up a few cents, because all single item transactions will be rounded up (e.g. every $3.99 purchase is $4.00 in the till.)

There do not *have* to be any programming changes to support the phase-out of pennies. You can choose to show the rounded amount on printed dockets, but it's not correct to presume anyone is lumbered with a mini Y2K or Euro implementation problem.

Comment: That may be the case with Australia, but Canada and others could be a different story. I would assume that most or all merchants would change the pricing of their products and services, rounded to the nearest desired denomination.

Comment: Hmm. Think about it. If they did that, then there'd be no problem to deal with in the first place!

Comment: really?... think about it again!